# How to connect to a linux machine that changes IP regularly?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

My problem is finding a way to SSH into a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04) whose IP address changes daily.

I have a client who I occasionally help with admin tasks. I need to ssh into the machine when they need help, but they don't have a static IP, so the public IP of the server is constantly changing. I created a small script to report the IP address of the Linux machine, and find that it changes once per day around noon.

I'm able to setup SSH, and it works both locally and remotely... until the IP address changes. Once that happens, I'm no longer able to connect remotely even using the new IP address.

- Do I need to restart the SSH service every time the IP address changes?
- If so, why?
- Is there any other action I need to take when the IP address changes in order to allow SSH access?

---

**UPDATE**

To be clear, my problem is NOT finding the new IP address. I have a script to do that already. The problem is the server stops responding once the IP changes, even though I try to connect using the new IP address.

If I restart the SSH service on the target machine, I have remote access again. But I don't understand why I should have to do this. I would like to know the root cause in hopes of finding a better solution.

Most people seem to think SSH should work as long as we know the new IP, so is this something unique to 18.04? I installed this server for the client recently, so all config settings are still default. (The wouldn't know how to change it.)

Comment: Use [dynamic dns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS).

Comment: Yell at their ISP. Changing IP address once a day is absurd for a business connection, and it's even relatively unheard of for a residential connection.

Comment: @IporSircer That would be a useful addition to the script which reports the IP address changes. But it doesn't address the problem with the machine being unreachable on the new IP address.

Comment: You say ssh access stops working when the IP address changes. But you haven't said when it starts working again. I assume it must somehow start working again, otherwise you couldn't see it stop working every day. And there isn't anything you are supposed to do when the IP address changes. The ssh server will immediately be reachable on the new IP address.

Comment: There could be some weirdness going on like DDNS running, and something like `ListenAddress <dynamic host name>` in the sshd config file, maybe because someone didn't want internal users being able to ssh into the server. This would actually require restarting the ssh server every time the IP changes.

Comment: @kasperd It starts working again once I locally restart the SSH server on the target machine. Then I can ssh both locally and remotely. If I need to restart the SSH service every time the IP changes, that's doable, but it didn't make sense to me that it should be necessary. So I would like to understand the root cause and hopefully find a better solution.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Yelling will probably not help, paying will. With the current scarcity of IPv4 addresses, most providers charge extra for a static IPv4 address (some even charge extra for a non-static public IP address, otherwise you get [Dual Stack Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Dual-Stack_Lite_.28DS-Lite.29)). Of course, if OP is on IPv6, things change...

Comment: Just to clarify: You are talking about an IP**v4** address, right? Or is this for IPv6?

Comment: @sleske OP mentioned in a comment to an answer that it is about IPv6. I really hope they will update the question. And hopefully add details about the network topology (Is the server behind a router? How does the server get its address, SLAAC, DHCPv6, ...? Is it a global address? Is some NAT used? Is there port forwarding on a the router? etc.)

Comment: @Richard How long time was it between the last time you tried to reach the machine before restarting sshd and until the first time you tried after restarting sshd? Could it be that the problem fixes itself after some time and you just happened to restart sshd during that time?

Comment: @OP does your provider use CGNAT? I've experienced what you describe a few times: I have a new IP but cannot connect remotely to any port. The way I fixed this is overly complicated, but basically involves a smart switch with my router plugged into it, a Raspberry Pi running hostapd and Home Assistant, and a Telegram bot! :-D If I get a new IP and can't connect, then I send the message "/reboot" to my bot, which in turn triggers the smart switch to turn off, wait ten seconds, and turn back on. Usually I get a 'good' IP after the first restart, but occasionally needs a couple :-)

Comment: @OP If you're constantly being CGNATed by your ISP then the other workaround you could try is reverse SSH. I have this configured with my Telegram bot as well: sending "/reverse <ip address>" gets it to try and open an SSH connection to the specified IP, with a reverse port-forward to the SSH port on the server (`-R 2222:localhost:22`); so I can then SSH to localhost:2222 and get in that way. These solutions of mine are a bit of a mess, and I imagine that they would get downvoted to oblivion if I posted them as an answer on this SE site :-)

Answer (score 22):

The other answers seem to have overlooked one thing in your question:

> Once that happens, I'm no longer able to connect remotely even using the new IP address

DDNS will help you find out the new IP address, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Unfortunately, the server getting a new IP *should* not be a problem in the standard setup where the ISP provides a router, the server has an internal address behind the router, and the router does the port forwarding. You might need to provide more information about the network topology to get a good answer.

What I could imagine is the server not being behind a router and doing its own PPPoE connection, *and* a) the ssh server binding to the specific interface address at the point of server restart, b) a firewall on the machine that permits incoming ssh to just the server's IP with the firewall not updating when the IP changes.

To check the first case, do a `netstat -nta | grep -w 22 | grep LISTEN`. If it says 0.0.0.0:22, that's ok; if it lists a specific IP, then check the sshd config file (`/etc/sshd.conf`) for `ListenAddress`.

To check the second case, do `iptables -L -n` and check if one of the rules in the `INCOMING` chain matches your server's IP and port 22.

If one of these has the current server address, you'll need to either change it to 0.0.0.0 (make sure you know about the security implications), or update the rule/configuration whenever the IP changes.

**Edit**

As the server is behind a router, the above ideas probably don't apply(*). In this setup, the router has an external IP (which changes daily), and your internal devices should have some 10.x.y.z or 192.168.x.y addresses which shouldn't change. You connect to the external address, and the router should a port-forwarding rule to the internal address.

This port forwarding shouldn't break when the external IP changes (existing ssh connections will be dropped however), but *maybe* it's a rule that wasn't setup by you, but by some UPNP magic, with the router dropping UPNP forwards when it gets a new address, and sshd only invoking the rule when it restarts. Did you set up a port forwarder within the router yourself.

Or, it's the *internal* IP of the server that changes - in that case, something is severely broken with your DHCP. Give your server a fixed internal address.

Or, are you using IPV6? There are some configurations where a device keeps changing its IP to make it less easy to track. See, for example, https://www.internetsociety.org/blog/2014/12/ipv6-privacy-addresses-provide-protection-against-surveillance-and-tracking/ - but in that case, shame on you for not mentioning it in your original post. This might mean your router not doing NAT at all, and my original ideas still being valid even behind a router.

Comment: +1 for being the first answer to actually address what was asked in the question.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm Thanks for the answer! The server is behind a router. Would these two possibilities still hold true in that scenario? If so, I'll check them both in the next day or so when I can locally access the target machine.

Answer (score 11):

Dynamic DNS is one option, another is having the server mail or otherwise send you it’s IP. A simple HTTP call would do (to an endpoint you control and log requests on).

Solving the whole public networking the the other way around is possible as well; you could have the server setup a reverse tunnel, or a VPN connection, which will not be affected by the IP change.

Regarding services not responding on the new address: this completely depends on your network setup. For example: WAN IP on an internal interface via DHCP and an SSH server set to only listen to the IP on your interface known at startup would mean sshd has to be restarted on interface changes.

Comment: As described in the question there is already a solution in place to find the new IP address. Thus adding dynamic DNS would not really solve any problems. The problem as described is that the ssh server stops responding when the IP address changes. You haven't addressed that problem. VPN connections and reverse tunnels are OTOH expected to stop working when the IP changes, so you need something in place to restart those automatically.

Answer (score 7):

You should really look into ddns services.
As far as remotely being able to connect to a certain machine with dynamic ip address; ddns is the most commonly used solution.

head over to https://noip.com and signup for an account (it's, errr... supposedly..coff..cof .. Free for 1-3 machines running on the same network(if im not mistaken, dont quote me here: its been a while since ive trusted any of these 'free' services... ). 
There are also other alternatives such as Afraid DNS (https://freedns.afraid.org/
And even, Cisco's, Open DNS : could also be utilized (provided that this is not you're only client, i'd suggest you sign up for an umbrella account trial, take it for a spin and later sign-up for the real deal >>> they even got one of them GUI-like downloadable extensions which would automatically renew the the ddns hostname 
 whenever your clients ip change. It really is, the easiest, non-tech savvy way that i'm aware of[just in case you gotta call up one of your clients and ask'm to download the GUI rather .... ])

Comment: While this is certainly helpful for accessing a host on changing IP addresses, that isn't what the question is asking about. The question is why the ssh server stops responding when the IP address changes and how to fix that. A dynamic DNS service does not address that.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm able to setup SSH, and it works both locally and remotely... until
>   the IP address changes. Once that happens, I'm no longer able to
>   connect remotely even using the new IP address.

Sometimes, it takes a while for DHCP changes to take effect. Try to recycle the DHCP client on the target machine

```
$> sudo dhclient -r
$> sudo dhclient
```

> ```
> Do I need to restart the service every time the IP address changes?
> If so, why?
> ```

No.  You only need to recycle your ssh service when the configuration changes (`/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`).

> Is there any other action I need to take when the IP address changes in order to allow SSH access?

No.

I have a solution that assumes you have sendmail set up on your target machine.

This script sends an email that shows the IP address that the world thinks we have (Thanks ipify.org).  Email will always have the most current IP address.

1. Create dhcp-notify bash script (without the .sh extension)
2. Put the script in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   case "$reason" in (BOUND|RENEW|REBIND|REBOOT)
   (
      echo To: me@my.email
      echo From: me@my.email
      echo "Content-Type: text/html; "
      echo Subject: DHCP reason: $reason
      echo
      echo Your IP address is: `curl -s https://api.ipify.org`
   ) | sendmail -t
   ;;
   esac
   ```

If this doesn't work, you could always set up a cron to send you the current IP address (lose the case statement).

```
#!/bin/sh
(
   echo To: me@my.email
   echo From: me@my.email
   echo "Content-Type: text/html; "
   echo Subject: IP address change
   echo
   echo Your IP address is: `curl -s https://api.ipify.org`
) | sendmail -t
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this, it's a great idea, and the first thing which came to mind when I read the question. Also, if you're having issues with https://api.ipify.org (it's blocked on my school network for some reason), you can use this other site which I made a few months previously which does the same thing: https://findip.win/

Comment: @karlchilders Thanks for the answer! I already have a cron script reporting the ip address to me, but I had no idea about dhclient hooks. That is awesome! I would much rather only have the IP reported when it actually changes.

Question:  If this script is able to work and report the IP address, why would recycling dhclient have an effect on SSH access?

Comment: @karlchilders  Or does this script only work when you manually recycle dhclient?

Comment: dhclient -r; dhclient will renew the dhcp lease so your host is current.  The hooks will work any time a dhcp event occurs either manually or otherwise.

Comment: @Richard Please mark one of the answers as the preferred answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking outside the box - could you arrange a fixed IPv6 address? It's usually only IPv4 addresses that need to change, due to their scarcity.

Comment: The IP address that I pull down is actually IPv6 every time.

Comment: @Richard: Sorry to hear it doesn't work for you. I'll leave the answer up for other people who have this problem with IPv4.

Comment: @Richard You should really mention in your question that you are dealing with IPv6. This makes the problem quite different.

Comment: @Dubu It does indeed make the problem different. This kind of problem just isn't supposed to happen on IPv6, which may be why everybody assumed it was IPv4. But in fact you could get some of the described symptoms if you mistakenly use a privacy address rather than a static address. If for example you ask a website what your IP address is, it will show your privacy address rather than your static address. And using that for ssh connections is not a good idea. Still doesn't explain why it doesn't work until the ssh server has been restarted.

Comment: @kasperd: At least with German Telekom, from time to time (e.g. with every router restart) you get a new IPv4 address _and_ new (GUA) IPv6 prefix. Fortunately, not every day. If this is the case, a stable ULA address on the server and port forwarding from the router _might_ be a possible solution here. Apart from "restart the server when a prefix change is detected."

Comment: @Dubu: That's a rather non-standard approach. DHCPv6-PD (Prefix Delegation) in combination with DHCP Unique ID's (DUID) should prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing for almost a year.
I ran into your problem in January this year while giving a speech at my local university.

This script has been running on my machine ever since then: 
//Pretty much self-explanatory//

```
import smtplib
from requests import get
import time

user = 'exampleemail@gmail.com'
psd = 'examplepassword'
msg = 'Hey, your ip has changed! Use this one from now on: '
currip = '0.0.0.0' # It'll send an email the first time you execute this aswell
while True:
    newip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
    if currip == newip:
        print("nonewip")
        #You can just comment the line above this one if you want to
    else:
        tmpmsg = "\n"+msg + newip +" The old one used to be: "+currip
        currip = newip
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.connect('smtp.gmail.com')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(user,psd)
        #You can change the second parameter, use ('from','to','message')
        server.sendmail(user, user, tmpmsg)

        server.quit()
        with open('/home/pi/DEV/iphistory.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('newip: '+currip+'\n')
            f.close()
        print('New IP Found: '+tmpmsg)
    time.sleep(7200)
```

Python 3.x should work flawlessly
Maybe not the best solution out there, but it works.

You'll get an email in your Inbox each time the machine's public IP changes.

Now, regarding your questions:

**Do I need to restart the service every time the IP address changes?**
*If by restarting the service you mean re-establishing the ssh connection, yes.*

**If so, why?**
*Because if the address you're trying to communicate with no longer provides the service you're looking for. It's not your machine anymore.*

**Is there any other action I need to take when the IP address changes in order to allow SSH access?**
*Just SSH to the new address.*

Cheers!
JSR

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JSR! I have actually written a similar script to report the IP address to me. But once it changes, even knowing the new IP address, I'm unable to SSH into the remote machine. Have you encountered that issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're retrieving the right address? if so, try to ping at it once you get the IP. I've never seen that issue before
Also, just in case you didn't know, you can run the script on background with "python3 scriptname.py &"

Also, check the forwarding ports of the router, I assume the local IP doesn't change, but still it's worth checking out.

Comment: Yes, the IP is correct. If I restart the SSH service on the target machine, I'm able to connect again. But I don't understand why that should be the case.

Comment: @Richard the issue here is that since your IP changes, your host stops every connection since the RSA Key you're using to authenticate does not match with the one it's requesting.

I'm by no means an expert on this topic, so don't take my words as a fact... But your situation is like that PROBABLY because of what I just said.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need remote login, use [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu). Apart from being able to cope excellently with IP changes (with almost no latency during the switch) it has also other advantages over plain `ssh`, like local predictive echo, low latency, way faster recovery from broken links.

If you specifically need `ssh` (say, you need X11 forwarding or something), I suggest setting up VPN (e.g. OpenVPN), preferably over UDP, with a short keepalive. TCP connections (i.e. your ssh) over VPN will heal and remain connected after IP change, it will just take longer (up to a minute or so), but you can play with `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_*` entries to make it more acceptable.

**Edit:**

- mosh needs `ssh` for authentication, but once authenticated, the connection stays until you log out (or reboot), and you can investigate the failure of `ssh` at your leisure (e.g. strace -f -p *pid_of_sshd*)
- it is possible to use `mosh` without `ssh`, answer adapted from [here](https://mosh-devel.mit.narkive.com/XmqBhmVU/mosh-without-ssh):

On the server run:

```
mosh-server new -p $randomport -- $shellprogram
```

you get an result like `QzdRHbAWzL7eRobi75DCrz`

On the client run:

```
MOSH_KEY=QzdRHbAWzL7eRobi75DCrz mosh-client $serverip $radomport
```

Note that `$serverip` has to be an ip, no hostname resolution.

How you get the key from one side to the other is up to you. I'd suggest encrypting with a pre-shared key and instant-messaging, mailing, or making a local user dictate it via phone call.

- if there is really a problem with `ssh`, install `inetd` and run ssh from there, not as a standalone daemon, e.g. by this configuration line for "classic" inetd.conf, this will run a new daemon each time you log in (note that not all inetd forks handle ipv6):

`ssh    stream    tcp6    nowait    root /usr/sbin/sshd    sshd -i`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Radovan! Mosh looks interesting, but it looks like it uses SSH to authenticate. So the root of my problem would still exist, correct? Let me know if I have misunderstood the docs.

Comment: @Richard Yes, however there are possibilities... I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth viewing this from a different side: usually, it's much simpler to **create an outward connection** from the machine that requires your attention (DNS, NAT and other firewall settings do not matter at all or are much simpler).

You could use this to establish a bullet-proof and simple solution to get into a remote machine `R`. The only requirement is that you can provide public `ssh` access to one of your own local machines (let's call it `S`). Then proceed as follows:

1. Create outward `ssh` connection from `R` to `S`, **establishing a reverse tunnel back into `R`**:

   `ssh -L 22:<address-of-S>:22000`
2. On `S`, use the reverse tunnel to `ssh` into the remote machine `R`:

   `ssh -p 22000 127.0.0.1`

Step 1 could be triggered manually and on-demand by the remote side whenever your assistance is needed. Alternatively, you could create a service on `R` that will continously maintain such a reverse tunnel to `S`.

I used such a setup to log into remote (mobile) systems that were behind firewalls/NAT and which had no DNS entries at all.